# Filter ip returned and name server into a dictionary. bash

Tags: bash, dictionary, awk, format

I have a file like so:
Example1:

```
haproxy-1
google_b 127.0.0.1
haproxy-2
google_b 127.0.0.1
haproxy-3
google_b 127.0.0.2
```

The file might have multiple values for the ips like so:
Example2:

```
haproxy-1
google_b 127.0.0.1
google_b 127.0.0.2
haproxy-2
google_b 127.0.0.1
google_b 127.0.0.2
haproxy-3
google_b 127.0.0.1
google_b 127.0.0.2
```

The only variabe i can go by is the google_b variable.
Ips and name servers are unknown but can be sorted via awk regex.
My goal is to take each ip the servers returned and put it into a dictionary.

The dictionary key needs to be the IP returned (if multiple ips then the multiple ips).
The dictionary value needs to be the server that returned that answer.

In general i want a dictionary to look like so:

For example 1:

`haproxy_results=( ["127.0.0.1"]="haproxy-1 haproxy-2" ["127.0.0.2"]="haproxy-3")`

For example 2:

`haproxy_results=( ["127.0.0.1"]="haproxy-1 haproxy-2 haproxy-3" ["127.0.0.2"]="haproxy-1 haproxy-2 haproxy-3")`

Example 3:

```
haproxy-3
google_b 127.0.0.1
google_b 127.0.0.2
haproxy-4
Can't find backend
```

How i do this now is i get the values for each server seperatly, format them to get the returned ips and the server and just add it to the dictionary like so:

haproxy-server is the `haproxy-1` or `haproxy-2` etc...

haproxy_ip_returned is the ips `127.0.0.1` `127.0.0.2` etc...

`haproxy_results+=([$haproxy_ip_returned]+=$haproxy-server)`

This is bad because i use ansible to get the data and ssh to each server seperatly causes the code to be very slow.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Oops. it posed it twice when i pressed post probably, deleting second one, ty :D

Comment: If your real input can contain lines that do not start with google_b and you only want the google_b IP addrs then you should include such lines in your example.

Comment: Unless there's some non-obvious reason to have 3 separate ones, combine your 3 examples to 1 sample input that covers all of your needs and add the associated expected output for that. If 3 separate inputs are necessary for some reason then explain why and add the 3 separate expected outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ eval declare -A haproxy_results=( $(
    awk -v tgt='google_b' '
        NF == 1 {
            srvr = $0
        }
        (NF == 2) && ($1 == tgt) {
            srvrs[$2] = ($2 in srvrs ? srvrs[$2] OFS : "") srvr
        }
        END {
            for (ip in srvrs) {
                printf "%s[\"%s\"]=\"%s\"", sep, ip, srvrs[ip]
                sep = OFS
            }
            print ""
        }
    ' file
) )
```

```
$ declare -p haproxy_results
declare -A haproxy_results=([127.0.0.2]="haproxy-1 haproxy-2 haproxy-3" [127.0.0.1]="haproxy-1 haproxy-2 haproxy-3" )
```

**Warning:** that use of `eval` will expose the contents of your file to the shell for interpretation and so variables like `$PWD` and commands like `$(ls)` in the input will be expanded so only use it if you're sure such constructs cannot occur in your input. More robustly but slightly less efficiently you can do:

```
$ declare -A haproxy_results

$ while read -r ip srvrs; do
    haproxy_results["$ip"]="$srvrs"
done < <(
    awk -v tgt='google_b' '
        NF == 1 {
            srvr = $0
        }
        (NF == 2) && ($1 == tgt) {
            srvrs[$2] = ($2 in srvrs ? srvrs[$2] OFS : "") srvr
        }
        END {
            for (ip in srvrs) {
                print ip, srvrs[ip]
            }
        }
    ' file
)
```

```
$ declare -p haproxy_results
declare -A haproxy_results=([127.0.0.2]="haproxy-1 haproxy-2 haproxy-3" [127.0.0.1]="haproxy-1 haproxy-2 haproxy-3" )
```

The above assumes that in your real data you have IP addresses for input that doesn't start with google_b and you want to ignore those. If that's not the case then get rid of `-v tgt='google_b'` and `&& ($1 == tgt)`.

Comment: What needs to be changed if the output instead of `google_b 127.0.0.1` is just: `Can't find backend`
Edited questions as an example

Comment: Sorry for the hustle and chaning, my code went through review yesterday and was suggested to keep the "Can't find backend" in the filter and not just ignore it (like i did previously)

Comment: Can u also explain how the code works? :D

Comment: AFAIK nothing needs to be changed if you want it ignored, if you don't want it ignored then show in your question what you want done with it. Did you try it? Does it do what you want or not?

Comment: Regarding explaining it - what part isn't obvious after you look up the man pages and google a bit, the part populating the shell array or some part(s) of the awk script?